# Joomla CSP error with facebook like box

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, joomla

I am receiving this error message in Chrome console. I use Joomla 3.7.5 with standard Joomla .htaccess. I didn't modify any CSP rules.

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/xti.php?xt=AZXZjy9jajOhaBIFiGzslo1yFRuStXr-L5Xf2gqNFJxSJgR4xoi7ZxJJRmFwYuUrvEtdf2FGBBFog-QwqbqJ8ben2Wkw3at9Mt0quOGc7Ey318SmJbfuvr2zGqUEGGpeOzU&isv=1&cts=1505470323&csp' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
4IIdQbYnq84.js?_nc_srcc=2812:19 GET https://www.facebook.com/xti.php?xt=AZXZjy9jajOhaBIFiGzslo1yFRuStXr-L5Xf2gqNFJxSJgR4xoi7ZxJJRmFwYuUrvEtdf2FGBBFog-QwqbqJ8ben2Wkw3at9Mt0quOGc7Ey318SmJbfuvr2zGqUEGGpeOzU&isv=1&cts=1505470323&csp net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
```

How can I fix this error message?

Comment: Please add some of your trial and errors. In this way people will be more attracted to your question

Comment: `X-Frame-Options` isn’t CSP. // Unless you did not embed this in the way outlined in the FB documentation, there is probably little you can do about that.

Comment: where can i start searching for problem?